# Industry Standards of Polymer Leeching Measurement

Tags: organic-chemistry, reference-request

I am a research assistant currently researching the leaching of polymers the byproducts of the reaction of ethanol and wood coating from wood billets into water and I'm at a crossroads with my colleagues.

Do the the somewhat niche nature of the research, it is difficult to find a standardized method of testing leeching from wood. Is there a format approved and tested by NIST or is it wisest to search the literature for a tested method and build from there?

Comment: If you want to do scientific research, the answer must be *search the literature!* in any case. ANY scientific research must start with an exhaustive literature study.

Comment: Leaching may be a better word than polymer leeching. You have to find target molecules of interest in order to be reasonable and meaningful literature search.